# ng-repeat display key value in view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

http://jsfiddle.net/qq2L34eb/1/

I want to display Monday but the value attr is equal to one using ng-repeat.

```
$scope.days = [{
    "Mondays": 1
}, {
    "Tuesdays": 2
}];
```

But I got the entire object instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/qq2L34eb/1/

Any clue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use another ng-repeat inside,

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <span ng-repeat="(key, value) in days">
    <span ng-repeat="(key, value) in value">
                   <input type='checkbox' value="{{value}}" check-list='checked_days'> {{key}}
    </span>
   </span>
</div>
```

DEMO

http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/2obrb921/

Comment: uh this is ugly, maybe I need to give a property name for the object

Comment: you can have something like this https://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/q4vv354e/

Answer (score 0):

2 things -

1) Your object array can be changed.

Your `$scope.days` is an array, it should be object instead.
Like this

```
  $scope.days = {
    "Mondays": 1
  , 
    "Tuesdays": 2
  }
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e8muqa3v/)

2) If you don't wish to change object array then add another `ng-repeat` within that like this. Like @Sajeetharan mentioned -

```
<span ng-repeat="(key, value) in days">
<span ng-repeat="(key, value) in value">
               <input type='checkbox' value="{{value}}" check-list='checked_days'> {{key}}
</span>
</span>
```

Answer (score -1):

According to your js fiddle in html write---

```
<span ng-repeat="pp in days">
    <input type='checkbox' value="{{pp.key}}" check-list='checked_days'> {{pp.value}}
</span>
```

In Controller---

```
 $scope.days = [{
    "key": "1","value":"Monday"
  }, {
    "key": "2","value":"Tuesday"
  },  ]
```

you can find result like this--

[image]

js fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/qq2L34eb/2/